# Nothing in my JFrame is appearing

Tags: java, user-interface

Every time I try and run the program, only an empty window appears and I cannot figure out why. I was able to have everything appear in the window previously when I had pretty much everything inside the main method, but now when I try something different, it just won't appear and closing it won't stop the program from running even though I thought I accounted for that in my code. There may be other problems with the code but the only one I really need help with is this one.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class AirplaneSeats extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final int FRAME_WIDTH    = 400;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT   = 300;
private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 250;

private JLabel reservetype = new JLabel("Select Reservation Type:");
private JLabel greenseat = new JLabel("Select availiable (green numbered) seat:");

private JButton firstclass;
private JButton coach;

private JButton one;
private JButton two;
private JButton three;
private JButton four;
private JButton five;
private JButton six;
private JButton seven;
private JButton eight;
private JButton nine;
private JButton ten;
private JButton eleven;
private JButton twelve;
private JButton nothing;

public static void main(String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Island Airlines");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public AirplaneSeats(){
    Container contentPane;

    contentPane= getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);

    setTitle("JMenuFrame: Testing Swing Menus");
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocation(FRAME_X_ORIGIN,FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    reservetype.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 20);
    greenseat.setBounds(10, 100, 250, 20);

    contentPane.add(reservetype);
    contentPane.add(greenseat);

    firstclass = new JButton("first class");
    coach = new JButton("coach");

    contentPane.add(firstclass);
    contentPane.add(coach);

    firstclass.setBounds(60, 40, 80, 35);
    coach.setBounds(150, 40, 80, 35);

    firstclass.addActionListener(this);
    coach.addActionListener(this);

    one = new JButton("1");
    two = new JButton("2");
    three = new JButton("3");
    four = new JButton("4");
    five = new JButton("5");
    six = new JButton("6");
    seven = new JButton("7");
    eight = new JButton("8");
    nine = new JButton("9");
    ten = new JButton("10");
    eleven = new JButton("11");
    twelve = new JButton("12");
    nothing = new JButton("");

    one.setBounds(20, 120, 30, 30);
    three.setBounds(60, 120, 30, 30);
    five.setBounds(100, 120, 30, 30);
    seven.setBounds(150, 120, 30, 30);
    nine.setBounds(190, 120, 30, 30);
    eleven.setBounds(230, 120, 30, 30);
    two.setBounds(20, 160, 30, 30);
    four.setBounds(60, 160, 30, 30);
    six.setBounds(100, 160, 30, 30);
    eight.setBounds(150, 160, 30, 30);
    ten.setBounds(190, 160, 30, 30);
    twelve.setBounds(230, 160, 30, 30);

    contentPane.add(one);
    contentPane.add(two);
    contentPane.add(three);
    contentPane.add(four);
    contentPane.add(five);
    contentPane.add(six);
    contentPane.add(seven);
    contentPane.add(eight);
    contentPane.add(nine);
    contentPane.add(ten);
    contentPane.add(eleven);
    contentPane.add(twelve);
    contentPane.add(nothing);

    one.addActionListener(this);
    two.addActionListener(this);
    three.addActionListener(this);
    four.addActionListener(this);
    five.addActionListener(this);
    six.addActionListener(this);
    seven.addActionListener(this);
    eight.addActionListener(this);
    nine.addActionListener(this);
    ten.addActionListener(this);
    eleven.addActionListener(this);
    twelve.addActionListener(this);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Comment: In 99% of situations, using a `null LayoutManager` is a horrible idea.

Comment: Amen to @Jeffrey's recommendation. It may seem like an easy to to create a GUI to start with, but null layout is an absolute bear to try to upgrade and maintain. Better to let the layout managers and the component's preferred sizes create the best most natural layout.

Comment: @Jefferey Oh i see. Lol I am still learning guis and I keep getting mixed messages when it comes to LayoutManagers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your main method to

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   AirplaneSeats airplaneSeats = new AirplaneSeats();
   airplaneSeats.setVisible(true);
}
```

You have `JFrame frame = new JFrame("Island Airlines");` which just creates a blank jframe.

Answer (score 1):

In your main method, you just create and display a plain vanilla JFrame object, not a AirplaneSeats object. Perhaps you want to instead create and display your AirplaneSeats object?

Comment: Thank you! It all appears now just perfectly!

Comment: @Lucas: sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes to look at the code.